# JavaScript / Ajax: Multiple Forms for one Script. How to consider only the submited one?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, submit

I have multiple Forms on one Page with differend IDs which get performed with AJAX:

```
<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="1" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="comment">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="2" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="comment">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

AJAX is actually working well, but considers only the input values of the first form. I'm pretty shure it's because it's all the same class and it does not differ between the IDs (1,2..)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.testForm').submit(function(event) {

        var formData = {
            'name'      : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'comment.php', 
            data        : formData, 
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true
        })

            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data); 

                if (data.success) {
                    $('.testForm input[type="submit"]').addClass('red');
                }

            });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
</script>
```

I want to have only class `red` added on the submit button, that was clicked.

I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, i'm pretty new to this and i could not really find helpfull stuff.

Comment: You can create a hidden input to each form and set them some different value for example, for the first form set hidden input value to 1 and for the second form set it to 2 and then find forms by these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `this.id`:

```
$('.testForm#'+form.id+' input[type="submit"]').addClass('red');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.testForm').submit(function(event) {
    var form = this; // capture correct this
    console.log(form.id) // should be 1 or 2 depending on the form

    var formData = {
      'name': $(form).find('input[name=name]').val(),
      'comment': $(form).find('input[name=comment]').val()
    };
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
      })

      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(form.id)

        if (data.success) {
          $(form).find('input[type=submit]').addClass('red')
        }

      });

    event.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="1" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="n1">
  <input type="text" name="comment" value="c1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="2" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="n2">
  <input type="text" name="comment" value="c2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="3" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="n3">
  <input type="text" name="comment" value="c3">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="comment.php" class="testForm" id="4" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="n4">
  <input type="text" name="comment" value="c4">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can also capture the correct form by using jQuery's `$.fn.find()`, like [@pschichtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827771/pschichtel) wrote in his comment:

```
$(form).find('input[type=submit]').addClass('red')
```

Comment: `$(form).find('input[type=submit]').addClass('red')` would be a little cleaner

Comment: You are right, I'll add a comment about it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a syntax error on let form = this;

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? Because of `let`? I now changed it to `var` please specify your JS version in the next question you ask if it's not the latest :-P

Comment: I don't know it's only showed in Dreamweaver that there is something incorrect ;D PLUS: you write "console.log(form.id) // should be 1 or 2 depending on the form". Actually i wanted to have it flexible. I don't want to specify the ID in the Script because it has to work for ALL my forms (there are a lot more after 1 and 2).. Or i'm i getting it wrong?! Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Yes, you are getting it wrong, if all forms have an ID (doesn't matter what it says) the code will select the form with that ID, not just 1 and 2

Comment: Nearly PERFECT ;D Thank you. BUT the last problem i am facing: Since my form inputs have the same names (name, comment), only my values from the FIRST form are getting processed. So if i submit my second Form, it considers the values that are typed in my first form..

Comment: In that case, let me re-write my answer, I didn't consider that before! Like this

Comment: You just have to do all operations in the scope of the form. You are currently selecting every input on the page, even though you only want those of the form being triggered. As `.val()` doesn't really make sense for multiple values, jQuery decided that it only returns the values of the first element that matched. So instead of using `$('something something')` use `$(this).find('something something')`. jQuery will set `this` to the HTMLFormElement that is trying to submit its data.

Comment: The explanation was for @muzzie.

Comment: This is just perfect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Only url: './', is not working. I replaced it with comments.php. That's fine

Comment: Sure, I removed that as to not provoke errors from stacksnippets